# set value when not empty via ternary expression

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have a really quick question for you:

I read data from an Excel sheet and want to transform it into an assoc array. But sometimes there are no values given in some cells. So if this occurs I want to set the value of the array to 0.

right now I do it like that with the ternary operator and I'm glad I discovered that today:

```
(isset($excel->sheet[0]['cells'][$row][$value]) ? $excel->sheet[0]['cells'][$row][$value] : 0)
```

Is there a whay to shorten the repitition in this case? It works but it ain't that pretty :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is not recommended, I would go the following way (PHP 5.3):

```
(@$excel->sheet[0]['cells'][$row][$value] ? : 0);
```

Error suppression operator is a mess, but in this case the only thing you suppress is a well-known notice about undefined variable.

Another option (as stated by [Álvaro G. Vicario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/lvaro-g-vicario)) could be a simple cast to `int` (as `NULL` casts to `0`):

```
(int)@$excel->sheet[0]['cells'][$row][$value];
```

Comment: In you decide to suppress errors, you can just cast to number: `(int)@$excel->sheet[0]['cells'][$row][$value]` or `(float)@$excel->sheet[0]['cells'][$row][$value]`

Comment: Thanks for this quick way. thought that `? : 0` does nothing on the true branch but that makes it shorter.
Àlvaros solution looks good too, since there is no decision making. Will try both. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Sebastian empty true branch means "just return the test expression value"

Answer (score 0):

Another option is making a function to check the existence of such variable – maybe it's a little over-engineering, overkill or just too much –:

```
function iset($array, $output) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $val = $array;
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($args) - 1; $i++) {
        if (!isset($val[func_get_arg($i)])) {
            return func_get_arg(func_num_args() - 1);
        }
        $val = $val[func_get_arg($i)];
    }
    return $val;
}
```

Then use the function like this:

```
$var = iset($excel->sheet, 0, 'cells', $row, $value, "DEFAULT_VALUE");
```

Comment: Another way that leads to the solution but it's kind of bloated for this small thing to do. Thanks for responding anyway